# Similarity percentage in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible in elasticsearch? Find records with similarity percentage and minimum percentage (like 30%) of similarity?

For example, we have the input lines “Hello” and “Hello, world!”, “Hello, friends!”. In this case, the percentage of similarity is 77.4% and 61.53%, respectively.

Can I get records with their similarities? And the record with the maximum similarity?